# MySQL Server Community 8.0

Tags: mysql

I started using the MySQL Community 8.0 database four days ago, and I have been running queries on it as part of a learning exercise.

I have tried to shut down the Server, but it has always resulted in a "Not Responding" mode. And I have to physically shut down the window process.

My question is whether this is  a bug.  I tried to contact Oracle Support but gave up after changing passwords five times to log in. And if its not a bug, ie. the MySQL Server is supposed to run continuously.  So, from a PC user perspective, we are used to starting up and shuttling down our computers, and I would expect to do the same with the MySQL database.

Is there anything I can be informed of. And should I just leave the MySQL 8 Server database running.

Comment: How did you try to shutdown the server?  What did you do?  What do you mean by "Not Responding" mode?  What it is not responding to?

Comment: I used the startup/shutdown instance of the MySQL Server. I wanted to ask if shutting down a MySQL session is okay/not okay. This is different from using a desktop database when it is not necessary to connect to, start up, run the server etc. And hopefully shut it down when the task is completed. Or should I keep the MySQL database running forever.

Comment: There is no strong reason not to just leave it running.  Assuming that you have set the string passwords on the MySQL server's admin account, etctera.  (Sure it will use some RAM ... but if you don't need it for other thing ...)

Comment: (I meant **strong** passwords ...)